# how to import Android-DirectoryChooser

Tags: android, import

i'm triing to use this directory picker: [Android-DirectoryChooser](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser)

if i import it in eclipse like: file -> import -> existing and. proj. -> directory picker -> library and sample project

it gives this errors:
[image]

what am i doing wrong?or how to implement it in the right way?

errors:

```
The declared package "net.rdrei.android.dirchooser" does not match the expected package "main.java.net.rdrei.android.dirchooser"
```

Comment: may i know the error what u r getting..............

Comment: i made an edit in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the package name at top of the class ,It is the starting statement of your class and your own package ,where your getting the error right click on that you will have your own package...

Comment: i've renamed the package and deleted the test package and now it works thank you!